# How to keep service running (not restarting) when user closes app?

Tags: java, android, service

i know return START_STICKY will prevent the service from dying, but the problem is that it restarts the service and this doesn't work efficiently in my app where i need to keep tab on the time to notify user when time's reached.
if i use return START_NON_STICKY, the service will stop and this is not what i want either

Comment: There is literally NO CHANCE IN HELL to prevent the process of **Automatic Restart of Service when the app is closed**, using START_STICKY. There is no way out of it as the android system is going to restart your service anyway when the app is closed. You have to manage the restart issue in the service code keeping in mind that the service will restart itself upon destruction of Activity

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting to keep track of time in the service.  Don't do that-  set an alarm when the timeout is reached instead.  If you need info about when the service was started, write it to disk, and delete it when no longer relevant.

Comment: @GabeSechan ooh ok :/ i guess i will try to use the alarm thing u were saying. how can i set an alarm btw? do u hv a simple example?

Comment: @ken not possible to do such thing till now